# selecting the table and some columns in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

I've two tables, and I want ist table and selected columns in another table in one query

Comment: hold up the Hat.. Show us the Rabit... Rabit = `code`

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You must have tried this yourself and then got stuck somewhere in the middle, right? Show us where you got stuck and we might be able to help. See the link provided by @jarlh . Otherwise, we can only come up with "use joins or union" as answer.

Comment: Hurry up and edit your question. (Otherwise it will soon be closed.)

Comment: I am using SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think at first you should read some of the basics in SQL syntax .

As for what you asked i the syntax is like this:
`Insert into yourtable1 (column1, column2 ) select column1 ,column2 from yourtable2 where yourcondition`